# Why do we have *Adapter classes in Spring Java Configuration when they are not Adapters in the general sense

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, design-patterns, naming-conventions, spring-java-config

When using Java configuration for Spring, you must seen classes like [WebMvcConfigurerAdapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.html)  & [HandlerInterceptorAdapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/HandlerInterceptorAdapter.html) which implement a single interface and they are following *Adpater convention which should have been reserved for a [real adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)(This specific class doesn't translate calls from one interface to a different interface).

Does any one know whether there is anything wrong with my understanding/they are using wrong convention?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adapter is also commonly used, at least in Java, to name base classes providing do-nothing implementations of all the methods of an interface. This is how Adapter must be understood in this context.

See for example [MouseAdapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html), [MouseInputAdapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/MouseInputAdapter.html), [MouseMotionAdapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseMotionAdapter.html), etc.

Comment: Looks to me like a mis-application of a term that otherwise is more explicit and clear. I feel a bit comforatble to understand NoOp<InterfaceName> incase of implementing single interface (or) NoOp<SomeMeaningfulName> in case if we are providing NoOp impl for multiple interfaces.